# Mysterious exported apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, export, apk

I have a weird problem with exporting apk. When I run the project on eclipse, it is working correctly. But if I export the apk and install the same phone after deleting old one, it is not the same application.It seems my last changes doesn't effect exported apk. It's like exported apk cached before and when i try to export, i always get the same apk file instead of new apk. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Clean build the project before creating apk. Also make sure your final destination folder does not contain other build in order to have ambiguity

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `bin` and/or `generated` folder in Eclipse. (Maybe also try to start like `eclipse -clean`)